# PHP and proper way of using the strcmp function

Tags: php

I am working on the following snippet. What is the point of using `!== 0` inside the first if condition while even the second condition is returning same result without using `!== 0`?

I was following some online tutorial and noticed that most developer are using the `!== 0` but I accidentally noticed that I am also getting same result back , at least in this specific example without using `!== 0`

```
<?php 
  
$name1 = "Geeks"; 
$name2 = "geeks"; 
  

if (strcmp($name1, $name2) !== 0) { 
    echo 'Strings are not equal'; 
} 
else { 
    echo 'Strings are equal'; 
} 

if (strcmp($name1, $name2)) { 
    echo 'Strings are not equal'; 
} 
else { 
    echo 'Strings are equal'; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Well, `0` is a falsey value, and anything else `strcmp` might return isn't, so yes, those conditions are equivalent. One is just more explicit than the other.

Comment: with !== instead of != you also check on being the same type of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "===" and "!==" comparison operators assert two things:

1. The values are equal, and
2. The values are of the same type

The short answer to your question "what is the point of using !== with the strcmp function" is simply "it's good practice". That's really the only reason regarding strcmp specifically, and != would give you the exact same result when it comes to that function.

The long answer is as follows:

PHP is traditionally a loosely typed language.  That is, datatypes were not all that important and PHP implicitly cast types for you automatically.  It still does this by default (although lots of stuff has been added to improve the situation over recent years). For example, if you add the string "1" to the integer 1, PHP will cast the string to an integer automatically and return the integer value 2. Strongly typed languages would return an error if you tried to do that.  Another example is that PHP will cast 0 to boolean false and any other non-zero value to boolean true.

It's that second example that causes problems with some of PHP's built-in functions.  For example, the strpos() function. If you check the [documentation page for strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) you'll see a big "Warning" in the "Return Values" section stating "This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE".  For that reason it advises you to use the "===" operator to make sure you are getting the exact value and type that you expect. So "=== 0" means the string was found at the beginning of the input, and "=== false" means the string was not found.  If you just used "== false" you won't be distinguishing between the string being found at the beginning of the input and the string not being found at all (because 0 will be implicitly cast to boolean false for the "if" statement).

So, developers got into the habit of testing for equality and type by using "===" and "!==".  It's a good habit.

Since strcmp always return an integer, and you are always comparing it to an integer, there is no implicit casting and so comparing types as well as equality is not neccessary.